# Linking WP categories and assigning posts in bulk

Tags: wordpress, post, custom-post-type, categories, custom-taxonomy

I am looking for a way to link categories in such a way, that e.g. if you assign few posts to a category, they will automatically be assigned to another category which is linked to the first one. Here is a real life example:

There are 3 categories: Ferrari, BMW, Mercedes

as well as the following ones: Fast, Slow, Blue, Yellow

I've got 20 posts and I assign them to the following categories: Ferrari, Fast, Blue

but then I change my mind and I decide that Ferrari isn't fast, so I need to unassign all those 20 posts from "Fast" and assign them to "Slow" category

Is there any way to link "Ferrari" and "Fast" categories, so that I could just do it all in one place - unlink it from "Fast" and assign to "Slow"? And that would affect all of the Ferrari posts.

Hopefully that makes sense. I would really appreciate your help. Thank you